# Is there an optimization for writing images or PDFs faster to the database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing an issue that my upload time for an image or PDF of 40+MB is more than 2.5 minutes (20+ seconds of which are just routing the request from the frontend to the backend but I'm worried more about the sql query slowlyness). I pasted some code snippets below. I also don't get an upload percentage indicator and the fetched bytes don't open as an image either in html using `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)" />` or using Win10 Photos app.

I'm looking first of all for an optimization on how can I write an image or pdf file faster into the database?

**Index.cshtml**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { @type = "file", @accept = "image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,application/pdf" })
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Model model)
    {
        var file = model.File;
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "File cannot be empty.");
            }
    
            const int maxFileSizeMB = 50;
            if (file.ContentLength > maxFileSizeMB * 1024 * 1024)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, $"File cannot be bigger than {maxFileSizeMB} megabytes.");
            }
    
            //Check for content-type, file extension, and first bytes if it's indeed a valid image.
            if (!file.IsImageOrPdfFile())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "File is not a valid image.");
        

    }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var fileName = file.FileName;
            var fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
            await _api.SaveFile(fileName, fileBytes);
            
            //success!
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index"));
        }
    }
    
    //View with errors
    return View(model);
}
```

**API method**

```
public async Task SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] fileBytes)
{
    var client = CreateRestClient();
    client.Timeout = 300000;

    var request = CreateJsonPostRequest("File", new SaveFileRequest
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        FileBytes = fileBytes
    });

    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NoContent && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception(response.Content);
    }
}
```

**Backend API**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/File")]
public class FileController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IFileActionsRepository _fileActions;

    public FileController(IFileActionsRepository fileActions)
    {
        _fileActions = fileActions;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost, Route("")]
    public async Task Post([FromBody] SaveFileRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        if (request.FileBytes.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("request.FileBytes");
        
        _fileActions.SaveFile(request.FileName, request.FileBytes);
    }
}
```

**FileActionsRepository.cs**

```
public class FileActionsRepository : IFileActionsRepository
{
    private readonly IDataContext _dataContext;

    public FileActionsRepository(IDataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;

        //Get the ObjectContext related to this DbContext
        var objectContext = (_dataContext.Context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

        //Sets the command timeout for all the commands (since it's too slow)
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;
    }

    public void SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        //Using sql query (with update .write() block) since it's faster than entity framework linq-2-entities.
        _dataContext.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            "if exists (select FileName from Files with (updlock,serializable) where FileName = @FileName)"
            + " update Files set FileBytes .write(@FileBytes, 0, null), SysModified = GETDATE()"
            + " where FileName = @FileName"
            + " else"
            + " insert into Files (FileName, FileBytes, SysCreated)"
            + " values (@FileName, CONVERT(varbinary, '0x00'), GETDATE())"
            + " update Files set FileBytes .write(@FileBytes, 0, null)"
            + " where FileName = @FileName",
            new SqlParameter("@FileName", fileName),
            new SqlParameter("@FileBytes", fileBytes));
    }
}
```

Comment: don't store BLOBs in the database; instead, store pointers to storage

Comment: What is your actual table definition that you're trying to write to? Also why are you using a .WRITE statement but are replacing the full value by having an offset (starting point) of 0 and a length of null (all after start/infinite). I assume your DBMS is SQL Server (i don't know if others have the .WRITE so), you might want to tag it as such as well.

Comment: @MitchWheat I will try that in a bit although the preference was using blobs.

Comment: "although the preference was using blobs" - it's not just a question on storage. If it's non-relational data , store it in cheap BLOB storage (or the file system)

Comment: @DKramer My table definition is like this
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
 [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
 [FileName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [FileBytes] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 [SysCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [SysModified] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [FileId_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [FileId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [FileId] ASC
)
...

Comment: @DKramer ...WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: You can always [edit] your question to include relevant detail. As you've noticed, comments are a very poor medium for this.

Comment: @MitchWheat We tried using the filestream in sql server but that was slow too. I'll do the filesystem approach and let you know.

Comment: 2.5 mins for 40mb.... and `filestream in sql server but that was slow too`. This sound more like a problem with the SQL (server) that a aspnet one...

Comment: Please edit in your table definition to your question, comments aren't properly readable for this. Also do you really have a primary key (with only a single column) and a unique index on the same single column?

Comment: When you're updating an existing file it looks like you're updating it twice.

Comment: JSON isn't really a good transport for large binary data between your front end and back end. If it's using base64 encoding then your 40MB file becomes ~53MB. If it's sending it as a number[] then you'll have 3 digits and a comma for most octets so your 40MB file becomes 160MB. Not surprised that it takes 20+ seconds to encode it, send it and decode it again.

Comment: @MitchWheat we followed the filesystem approach (with references in the database) as it is much faster.